# Not able to read the model value using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium web driver. So I am trying to do some sample using different websites. In such pattern, I tried to work with OTTO website and trying to add the item to cart. Here comes the issue, On this website, there is a modal window before adding the item to cart.

My question is how to enter the modal window and access the elements inside it? Below is the code that I have tried it with.[Click here to view the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2kPa.jpg)

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class AutomationTesting {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/xxx/eclipse-workspace/seleniumTesting/lib/geckoDriver/geckodriver");
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("https://www.google.de");
     driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Pepe Jeans");
     driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("Pepe Jeans Online-Shop | OTTO")));
     driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Pepe Jeans Online-Shop | OTTO")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Pepe Jeans Chiffonkleid »MARY«, im modischen Leo-Muster")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul//li[@data-variationid='594838149']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.id("addToBasket")).click();
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("p_layer")));
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("or_itemAdded__itemInfo")));
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@data-qa='goToBasket']")));
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-qa='goToBasket']")).click();
     }
}
```

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Answer (score 0):

The modal window is simulated, not a actual browser window. So the HTML code of elements inside the modal window are in same page. Use DevTool you can simply to verify that.

All content of the modal window come from a DIV node which id is p_layer, So you can find inside element start from #p_layer

[image]

Comment: If you see above code, I have mentioned #p_layer. But still I am not able to access the inside elements.

Comment: did the code will failed at this line:  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("p_layer")));

Comment: It worked fine with wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.‌​id("p_layer"))); . When I am trying to click the button driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-qa='goToBasket']")).click(); then it is not able to find and go further.

Comment: Could you upload the error stack?  I tried the xpath: //a[@data-qa='goToBasket'],  it will match two element, but the second one is what you want to click.  I guess the error should say element not visible, because the first matched one is not visible, but your code will click on the first one. Please try your code to driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-qa='goToBasket'][2]")).c‌​lick();

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to access the element. 

Error: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //a[@data-qa='goToBasket'][2]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: It's strange, How about to try driver.findElemet(By.cssSelector("#p_layer [data-qa='itemInfo']  a[data-qa='goToBasket']")).click()